# Linq query with multiple joins and groups

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am quite new to linq expressions and am trying to work out the equivalent linq version of this tsql:

```
SELECT 
    p.Name, 
    Count(a.Street) [Number of addresses], 
    c.ContractType, 
    COUNT(cv.ContractVersionId) Number, 
    MAX(cv.ChangedDate) [Last change date] 
From Person p 
LEFT JOIN Address a ON p.PersonId = a.PersonId AND a.ChangedDate IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Contract c ON p.PersonId = c.PersonId
LEFT JOIN ContractVersion cv ON c.ContractId = cv.ContractId

GROUP BY p.Name,  c.ContractType
```

This produces the output:

```
Name    Number of addresses ContractType    Number  Last change date
Bob     1                   NULL            0       NULL
Allice  1                   Buy             1       2020-10-31 00:00:00.000
Karen   0                   Buy             3       2020-09-01 00:00:00.000
Peter   3                   Lease           3       2020-07-10 00:00:00.000
Tom     5                   Lease           5       2020-09-14 00:00:00.000
Allice  3                   Rent            3       2020-05-10 00:00:00.000
```

Data to reproduce:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Person]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].Person
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Address]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].Address
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Contract]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].Contract
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ContractVersion]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].ContractVersion
GO
CREATE TABLE Person (
        PersonId Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    )
CREATE TABLE Address(
        AddressId Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        PersonId Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        Street NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        ChangedDate DATETIME NULL
    )
CREATE TABLE Contract (
        ContractId Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        PersonId Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        ContractType NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    )
CREATE TABLE ContractVersion (
        ContractVersionId Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        ContractId Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        ContractText NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        ChangedDate DATETIME NULL
    )


INSERT INTO Person
VALUES
    ('{B8A97537-AF09-45FD-A723-1BF43796DADA}','Tom'),
    ('{124A34C0-1AB3-4449-AEE2-04ED2732B8ED}','Allice'),
    ('{E501CC32-C587-43C7-B0DD-096F04EE80AA}','Peter'),
    ('{9D1E37BE-D032-45CC-AA1D-06ECBB9C59EA}','Karen'),
    ('{049B5985-F4D0-448C-9391-8E08495DF61F}','Bob')
INSERT INTO Address
VALUES  
    ('{AF3BE020-6851-46E1-9D04-9959C665A80D}','{B8A97537-AF09-45FD-A723-1BF43796DADA}','Last address 1',NULL),
    ('{A0957F82-8922-452C-AA1B-4EA05A1B121B}','{124A34C0-1AB3-4449-AEE2-04ED2732B8ED}','Last address 2',NULL),
    ('{10D60EDC-75B3-412F-AA0B-962746EB72BD}','{E501CC32-C587-43C7-B0DD-096F04EE80AA}','Last address 3',NULL),
    ('{93A10053-5059-4127-8EA1-C0DF77760E84}','{049B5985-F4D0-448C-9391-8E08495DF61F}','Last address 4',NULL),
    ('{F1E838FE-7074-4AB3-8A4D-0895CEB98362}','{B8A97537-AF09-45FD-A723-1BF43796DADA}','D','2020-01-01'),
    ('{4CB0D80D-7F74-4755-9C1A-08A03EE88B4B}','{124A34C0-1AB3-4449-AEE2-04ED2732B8ED}','D','2020-01-01'),
    ('{B42DE51A-3EAD-4AAC-B5DC-75493FE214E5}','{E501CC32-C587-43C7-B0DD-096F04EE80AA}','D','2020-01-01')

INSERT INTO Contract
VALUES  
    ('{64989F02-793E-4313-9324-4916D6C5D610}','{B8A97537-AF09-45FD-A723-1BF43796DADA}','Lease'),
    ('{0101F8CD-E72E-4D9B-A8BD-A94BBDB39740}','{124A34C0-1AB3-4449-AEE2-04ED2732B8ED}','Rent'),
    ('{D1F94A9C-0718-4E18-B63F-B506C5E2C70E}','{E501CC32-C587-43C7-B0DD-096F04EE80AA}','Lease'),
    ('{A8397E6D-597A-4024-91DC-98EA0D9FF848}','{9D1E37BE-D032-45CC-AA1D-06ECBB9C59EA}','Buy'),
    ('{D47E82B3-2D41-4CCB-BD6F-003BD9C49BEA}','{B8A97537-AF09-45FD-A723-1BF43796DADA}','Lease'),
    ('{5EC4E588-00A5-442B-BD7B-0C9FD27E8076}','{124A34C0-1AB3-4449-AEE2-04ED2732B8ED}','Buy')
    
INSERT INTO ContractVersion
VALUES  
    ('{E3E26DE5-F00A-4BEB-9A48-72AE9EA29F2E}','{64989F02-793E-4313-9324-4916D6C5D610}','Created','2020-01-01'),
    ('{C5EFAB2E-EE41-4A10-A708-44CA19E505A9}','{0101F8CD-E72E-4D9B-A8BD-A94BBDB39740}','Created','2020-05-01'),
    ('{43EDFE20-B1EF-4236-8D4E-478F445EC327}','{D1F94A9C-0718-4E18-B63F-B506C5E2C70E}','Created','2020-06-03'),
    ('{16870733-0EC3-497B-BA51-770C921A245A}','{A8397E6D-597A-4024-91DC-98EA0D9FF848}','Created','2020-08-15'),
    ('{93CAEA22-D796-4237-A706-47C3D6AE8700}','{D47E82B3-2D41-4CCB-BD6F-003BD9C49BEA}','Created','2020-09-12'),
    ('{9D003A79-1376-4512-922F-88A33EC72CCB}','{5EC4E588-00A5-442B-BD7B-0C9FD27E8076}','Created','2020-10-31'),
    ('{8BD9E556-BB56-4404-A7C2-C6C06D321127}','{64989F02-793E-4313-9324-4916D6C5D610}','Reviewed','2020-01-05'),
    ('{E46D1C7E-94BF-43BC-883D-7960CE719C07}','{0101F8CD-E72E-4D9B-A8BD-A94BBDB39740}','Reviewed','2020-05-01'),
    ('{0B5B594C-78BF-49B7-834B-3E9A617A16F9}','{D1F94A9C-0718-4E18-B63F-B506C5E2C70E}','Reviewed','2020-06-08'),
    ('{931C3910-DFD6-4EB4-9826-9518B3C6BC54}','{A8397E6D-597A-4024-91DC-98EA0D9FF848}','Reviewed','2020-08-16'),
    ('{6F97D07E-9AAD-488E-87D3-D2A886547B1C}','{D47E82B3-2D41-4CCB-BD6F-003BD9C49BEA}','Reviewed','2020-09-14'),
    ('{BD3B3413-8853-4199-BC93-B23D49F77A9C}','{64989F02-793E-4313-9324-4916D6C5D610}','Finalized','2020-04-01'),
    ('{5DA560DE-69D7-4244-A320-AF3FE4135B22}','{0101F8CD-E72E-4D9B-A8BD-A94BBDB39740}','Finalized','2020-05-10'),
    ('{8392D528-438C-4F82-8BAC-69C1913CF610}','{D1F94A9C-0718-4E18-B63F-B506C5E2C70E}','Finalized','2020-07-10'),
    ('{0DC060B3-12F0-4927-8526-57E87C0150EA}','{A8397E6D-597A-4024-91DC-98EA0D9FF848}','Finalized','2020-09-01')
    

SELECT 
    p.Name, 
    Count(a.Street) [Number of addresses], 
    c.ContractType, 
    COUNT(cv.ContractVersionId) Number, 
    MAX(cv.ChangedDate) [Last change date] 
From Person p 
LEFT JOIN Address a ON p.PersonId = a.PersonId AND a.ChangedDate IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Contract c ON p.PersonId = c.PersonId
LEFT JOIN ContractVersion cv ON c.ContractId = cv.ContractId

GROUP BY p.Name,  c.ContractType
```

All help appreciated!

**Update:**
I can produce this linq expression but font understnad how I should go about the grouping since the data is in different tables.

```
from p in Persons
join a in Addresses on new { p.PersonId} equals new { a.PersonId} into addressGroup from a in addressGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c  in Contracts on p.PersonId equals c.PersonId into contractGroups from c in contractGroups.DefaultIfEmpty()
join cv in ContractVersions on c.ContractId equals cv.ContractId

select new {p.Name, a.Street, c.ContractType, cv.ChangedDate}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried @jdweng query below and the produced sql turned out like this:

```
SELECT [t5].[Name] AS [name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM (
            SELECT [t7].[Street] AS [value], [t6].[Name], [t8].[ContractType]
            FROM [Person] AS [t6]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [t7] ON [t6].[PersonId] = [t7].[PersonId]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contract] AS [t8] ON [t6].[PersonId] = [t8].[PersonId]
            INNER JOIN [ContractVersion] AS [t9] ON [t8].[ContractId] = [t9].[ContractId]
            ) AS [t10]
        WHERE ([t5].[Name] = [t10].[Name]) AND ((([t5].[value] IS NULL) AND ([t10].[ContractType] IS NULL)) OR (([t5].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t10].[ContractType] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t5].[value] IS NULL) AND ([t10].[ContractType] IS NULL)) OR (([t5].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t10].[ContractType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t5].[value] = [t10].[ContractType])))))
        GROUP BY [t10].[value]
        ) AS [t11]
    ) AS [numberOfAddresses], [t5].[value] AS [contractType], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [Person] AS [t12]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [t13] ON [t12].[PersonId] = [t13].[PersonId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contract] AS [t14] ON [t12].[PersonId] = [t14].[PersonId]
        INNER JOIN [ContractVersion] AS [t15] ON [t14].[ContractId] = [t15].[ContractId]
        WHERE ([t5].[Name] = [t12].[Name]) AND ((([t5].[value] IS NULL) AND ([t14].[ContractType] IS NULL)) OR (([t5].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t14].[ContractType] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t5].[value] IS NULL) AND ([t14].[ContractType] IS NULL)) OR (([t5].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t14].[ContractType] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t5].[value] = [t14].[ContractType])))))
        GROUP BY [t15].[ContractVersionId]
        ) AS [t16]
    ) AS [number]
FROM (
    SELECT [t4].[Name], [t4].[value]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[Name], [t2].[ContractType] AS [value]
        FROM [Person] AS [t0]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [t1] ON [t0].[PersonId] = [t1].[PersonId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contract] AS [t2] ON [t0].[PersonId] = [t2].[PersonId]
        INNER JOIN [ContractVersion] AS [t3] ON [t2].[ContractId] = [t3].[ContractId]
        ) AS [t4]
    GROUP BY [t4].[Name], [t4].[value]
    ) AS [t5]
```

It almost produces the result I want and takes 20 times as long time as the original tsql.

Comment: Are you using `entity framework`? If yes which version? & also share corresponding `Models`.

Comment: Right now I'm only working in Linqpad directly towards the tables above with linq expressions so there are no EFcontexts or models for them.

Comment: There is, it's generated by Linqpad. Take a look at the classes properties, esp. navigation properties and do some first attempts. There's not really a question here. You only tell what you want.

Comment: @GertArnold, I've updated with the ungrouped linq expression but I cant get my head around how to group the data

Comment: As often happens, you attack this with a SQL mind and immediately type joins. Start by designing a proper database model with primary and foreign keys. Linq-to-sql (which Linqpad uses) will then generate a model with navigation properties. If you got to that point, try to write some queries using these properties an d see what they do. Then you'll see you can simply do things like `p.Addresses.Count()`.

Comment: @GertArnold, Yes, the data provided is just a simplified example of course. There is an EFCore context with too many tables in it and there is a gigantic query that gets data with like p.Addresses.Count. It takes forever of course. And while one could argue "dont do that" the problem is there and someone wants a report that doesn´t time out. 
I

Comment: Still, it would be better to present the actual problem. There's little chance that a LINQ query based on the above model will get you any closer. For one, LINQ-to-SQL en EF are very different in SQL translation which, of course, will have great impact on the query plan. That said, for reports that don't run frequently it may be acceptable to increase the command timeout as a temporary work-around to get some breathing space to tackle the actual problem.

Comment: My plan was that I would gain increased knowledge to understand what was happening with the groups. Then I could apply that knowledge on the real problem. But might be that the best solution is to accept a stored procedure in this case and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how EF Core supports `Count` with condition, so just emulating with `Sum`.

```
var query =
   from p in Persons
   join a in Addresses on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId into addressGroup 
   from a in addressGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
   join c in Contracts on p.PersonId equals c.PersonId into contractGroups 
   from c in contractGroups.DefaultIfEmpty()
   join cv in ContractVersions on c.ContractId equals cv.ContractId in versionsGroup
   from cv in versionsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
   group new { a, cv } by new { p.Name,  c.ContractType } into g
   select new 
   {
       g.Key.Name, 
       NumberOfAddresses = g.Sum(x => x.a.Street != null ? 1 : 0), 
       g.Key.ContractType, 
       Number = g.Sum(x => x.cv.ContractVersionId != null ? 1 : 0), 
       LastChangeDate = g.Max(x => x.cv.ChangedDate)
   }
```

Comment: Don't think you need to left outer join.

Comment: @jdweng  Generated SQL should be equal to the question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, This produces exactly the same executionplan! Thanks!

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv : No!!!  The SQL language is very limited and often requires complex queries when they are not needed in the equivalent c# linq.

Comment: @jdweng, So what? This query is easily convertible via LINQ. And I think EF Core is very limited to produce needed SQL which is important if you do not want to grab whole table to the client and make post processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context db = new Context();

            var results = (from p in db.Person
                           join a in db.Address on p.PersonId equals a.PersonId
                           join c in db.Contract on p.PersonId equals c.PersonId
                           join cv in db.ContractVersion on c.ContractId equals cv.ContractId
                           select new { p = p, a = a, c = c, cv = cv}
                           ).GroupBy(x => new { name = x.p.Name, contractType = x.c.ContractType })
                           .Select(x => new { 
                               name = x.Key.name, 
                               numberOfAddresses = x.GroupBy(y => y.a.Street).Count(),
                               contractType = x.Key.contractType,
                               number = x.GroupBy(y => y.cv.ContractVersionId).Count(),
                               lastChangeDate = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.cv.ChangedDate).FirstOrDefault().cv.ChangedDate
                           })
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
        public List<Contract> Contract { get; set; }
        public List<ContractVersion> ContractVersion { get; set; }

    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
    }
    public class Address
    {
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }

    }
    public class Contract
    {
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string ContractType { get; set; }
        public string ContractId { get; set; }
    }
    public class ContractVersion
    {
        public string ContractId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }
        public string ContractVersionId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Here is 2nd query which may run quicker :

```
            var results =  db.Person.Select(p => new {
                Person = p,
                Address = db.Address.Where(a => p.PersonId == a.PersonId),
                Contract = db.Contract.Where(c => p.PersonId == c.PersonId),
                ContractVersion = db.ContractVersion.Where(cv => p.PersonId == cv.ContractId)
            }).GroupBy(x => new { name = x.Person.Name, contractType = x.Contract.FirstOrDefault().ContractType}) 
                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               name = x.Key.name,
                               numberOfAddresses = x.Select(y => y.Address.SelectMany(z => z.Street)).Count(),
                               contractType = x.Key.contractType,
                               number = x.GroupBy(y => y.ContractVersion.SelectMany(z => z.ContractVersionId)).Count(),
                               lastChangeDate = x.SelectMany(y => y.ContractVersion.Select(z => z.ChangedDate)).OrderByDescending(y => y).FirstOrDefault()
                           })
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks! I get a "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'outer')"  on the var results statement. Is that because the contracttype is null for one person?

Comment: It could be the date or the contractType.  You can comment out to find which one.  It is more likely the date since a date cannot be null.

Comment: This produces a somewhat close result but the TSQL that comes out of it is not nice at all. It is about 20 times slower than the SQL I'm trying to imitate. ( you can see the query in my update 2). 
Is there a way to create intermediate  groups and join those towards new tables?

Comment: Do query run slow also using SQL Server Management Studio?  Need to find out if the slow time is caused by the c#/sql interface or the actually the time to perform query.  It looks like the joins may nee to use WHERE instead.

Comment: Yes in the real world example they get very slow because the result is like "For every row make another select to another table where ids match" Meaning a query with 100 row in the first table would result in 101 "queries" to the database

Comment: I added another version that may be faster.